# Azure Storage Queue messages stay invisible for minutes

Tags: c#, azure, message-queue, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

As seen in the image below, queue items remain invisible for more than 7 minutes and no processing is being done in the meantime as Live Metrics Stream shows no processor activity until after the (roughly) 7 minutes. It is like the Queue Trigger is not being activated. The visilibityTimeout is set to '00:00:05'.

This happens very often and there are no exceptions or errors. Refreshing many times shows some of the messages appearing with a dequeue count of 1 and then instantly disappearing / getting processing (even if the QueueTrigger function is stopped).

The more servers online there are that process the queue messages the more messages are likely to get stuck in such a way.

This is how it is implemented:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(QueueFunc))]
public async Task QueueFuncProcess(
   [QueueTrigger("%QueueFuncName%", Connection = "QueueFuncConnection")] string queueItem)
```

[image: Azure Storage Explorer]

Comment: what webjobs sdk version are you using

Comment: I believe it is v10.0.3. I have submitted this problem to Microsoft and they have been troubleshooting it for 3 days now. Turns out the queue items are not even hitting the trigger. They are being dequeued, but are being lost somewhere between dequeue and triggering the function.